# How do I establish a connection from my java program to sqlite3? Package error when attempting

Tags: java, sqlite, package

When I try to connect to my database; it throws me these error:

```
PersonTidbok.java:3: error: package org.sqlite does not exist
import org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig;
                 ^
PersonTidbok.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
         SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();  
         ^
  symbol:   class SQLiteConfig
  location: class PersonTidbok

PersonTidbok.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
         SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();  
                                   ^
  symbol:   class SQLiteConfig
  location: class PersonTidbok
3 errors
```

From the following code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig;

public class PersonTidbok {

   public static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/zeren/SQlite/slutuppgift";   

   public static final String DRIVER = "org.sqlite.JDBC";  

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      Connection conn = null;

      try {
         Class.forName(DRIVER);
         SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();  
         config.enforceForeignKeys(true); 
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,config.toProperties());  
      } catch (Exception e) {

         System.out.println( e.toString() );
         System.exit(0);
      }


   }

}
```

The code was given from my teacher for our final assigment, and im wondering why he'd include a package that doesnt exist somehow? How doesnt package org.sqlite not exist? I dont get it, someone help me" :C

Comment: Does your project in well configured? Libraries path etc... ?

Comment: yeah path is correct, but it just says that the package org.sqlite doesnt exist. so import org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQLiteConfig** is a class which is an integral part of the **sqlite-jdbc-3.x.x.jar** JDBC driver JAR file. If this is failing then obviously you driver jar file can not be found within the classpath. Be sure to add the `sqlite-jdbc-3.x.x.jar` file to your project.

If in Netbeans:

- With your mouse, click once on the project name from the **Projects**
  pane (on left of IDE) so that it is highlighted;
- Righ-click and select the **Properties** option from the popup menu
  that appears (at bottom). The **Project Properties** dialog window
  will appear;
- In the Categories pane (on left side of the Project Properties
  window) select **Libraries**;
- You should see the **sqlite-jdbc-3.x.x.jar** file within the
  *Compile-time Libraries* list (x.x would of course be the version numbers you want to use). If the driver JAR file is shown in the list then hit the  <kbd>Cancel</kbd>  button located at the bottom of the Project Properties
  window. You do have the driver as part of your project.
- If the driver JAR file is not shown in the list then select the 
  <kbd>Add Jar/Folder</kbd>  button located on the right side of the
  *Compile-time Libraries* list;
- An **Add Jar/Folder** navigation dialog will appear. Navigate to
  where you have stored your copy of the **sqlite-jdbc-3.x.x.jar**
  Driver JAR file and select it then hit the  <kbd>Open</kbd>  button.
  The Navigation dialog window will close and your selected JAR file will be
  displayed within the *Compile-time Libraries* list;
- Select the  <kbd>OK</kbd>  button located on the bottom of the
  *Project Properties* window. The *Project Properties* window will close.
- You now have the **sqlite-jdbc-3.x.x.jar** driver added to your
  project. You may need to save your work and close the NetBeans IDE,
  then reopen it for the SQLite JDBC driver to take affect. Test your
  code.

I can't help you with other IDE's since I simply don't use them.

The code you provided works for me. Because you have managed to import **org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig** basically tells me that you do have the driver included within your project **but**, since the code was given by your teacher then a copy/paste would account for the import but its validity would be highlighted (or underlined) in some fashion via the IDE indicating an error.

Comment: yeah im a noob. I do have the jar file, i have the java file and the jar file as a project in my jgrasp enviroment. im noob because i never clicked compile i just clicked ran, in which i got the error because i suppose the program needs to not only have the connectivity setup but also needs programming code i guess

Comment: There may be a setting in your IDE that allows the code to be automatically compiled when Run is selected (most good ones have this feature).

Comment: Got it, i think mine does so, i just thought it was interesting that comiling it works but not running it... may be because of the reasons i said above which is that i assume the program needs code that perform the actions inside the database

Answer (score 0):

In jGRASP, use "Settings" > "PATH / CLASSPATH" > "Workspace" (or project) then the "CLASSPATHS" tab to add the jar file to the classpath.